# Python - Scaling an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array that has 450 values. The x-axis goes from 0 to 449 (the 450 values) and the y-axis takes the values in the array from the first value to the last value in that array, and plots it against x.

I want to shift these x values along so the value of 0 now shows as 425 and the last value as 875. Do you know how I could do this?

I attached a photo of the graph and I want to shift the orange across so the first value corresponds to 425 and the last to 875, to match with the scale the blue graph is on.

Abs.shape returns `(450,)`.

My array reads:

```
[-3.03523031e-02  1.95809977e-02  5.05650282e-02  1.45853489e-01
  2.65848121e-01  2.63604947e-01  2.04795719e-01  9.65495343e-02
  3.47842310e-02...,2.04040018e-01]
```

[image: Image showing code and graph in question]

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post code/data/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Did you even TRY this before asking?  Because the obvious answer is the right answer.  Since it came from a pandas dataframe, your X axis is a numpy array.  That means you can say `x_axis += 425`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, you can define the spots in the x axis with `np.array(range(450,875))` in total it should look like this:

---

```
x_axis = np.array(range(450,875))
plt.plot(x_axis, data)
```